# On Error Resume Next not working in VBScript (VBS) when setting object

Tags: vbscript

I just want to test if the object was set. Seems simple enough to me.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objExcel, wMn
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
msgbox "test"
On Error Resume Next
Set wMn = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("Z:\path\file_*.xlsm")

msgbox "test1"
If Err.Number = 0  then
  msgbox "test2"
end if
On Error Goto 0
```

The msgbox "test" shows, but the msgbox "test1" and msgbox "test2" never show. I just hangs on the Set if the file is not there. VBS only please. Thanks.

I know I can use a file system object, but I am wondering why I can't do something like this.

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 2 (trailing comma). Other than that your code works fine. I'm guessing your *real* code is not what you show here.

Comment: 1. Does the `Workbooks.Open` method allow wildcards in file name? 2. `On Error Goto 0` statement does not only disable error handling; in addition, it clears properties of the `Err` Object, co you should move this statement _behind_ error handling code snippet. 3. Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` statement to see what really happens...

Comment: @Tomalak - I removed the trailing comma. You are correct, I simplified the code for the post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Excel does not support wild cards in the Open method.

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim objExcel, wMn

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    MsgBox "test"

    objExcel.Visible = True 'Otherwise you'll never see it

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wMn = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\actualfile.xls") 'Works
    'Set wMn = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\actualfil*.xls") 'Won't work even if only file that could match wild card

    MsgBox "test1"

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        MsgBox "test2"

    Else
        'Output error to help you work out what wrong...
        MsgBox "Err:" & Err.Description  

    End If

    On Error Goto 0
```